# Receive notifications on android upon database change

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications

I have an android app which is capable to interact with a (for now local, but in future online) RESTful database (using PHP and Slim framework).

A registered user can create/upload new text, view all its texts, delete and modify them.

The user can log through different devices (Android smartphones for now, but in future with Desktop computers as well) and perform said operations.

I need that EVERY device (on which the user is logged in) is notified upon each change in the database.

What is the best approach to implement such notification capability either on the PHP/MySQL server and in my android app?

I have heard about Google's Firebase Cloud Messaging but i'm not sure neither if it is the easiest and fastest way to do it, nor if it is compatible with my already working environment.

Please guide me in the right direction as i don't have a clue on what is best for my case.

Comment: search About Sockets

Comment: Look into Cloud Functions for Firebase to write backend code that triggers in response to database changes.

Comment: so, i'm digging into FCM but it seems that every call is per user basis (i.e you have to add the user key to the request), but i need something that works with a user its multiple devices. is it still viable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to registered mobile device or desktop to fcm/gcm server or apns in case of iOS . When database is updated on server then it will get a trigger so on after save will send notification push with your payload.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? How do i integrate FCM with my already working PHP REST api?

Comment: you have to read documentation for android here [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) or see demo here [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: ok thanks i'll look into them and see if that's what i'm looking for ^^